# Contacts not appearing on mailing labels

Tags: address-labels

Have a strange situation where 2000 contacts have been imported with address details. The addresses look fine but when you create a mailing label neither the contacts nor the addresses chosen appear. But when you go and edit/save the contact that contact does then appear on the mailing label, V strange.

I've tried clearing caches and I also though the scheduled job 'Update Greetings and Addresses' may be connected but this made no difference. Something happens when you save the contact but I can't see what it is.

Olly

Comment: Please check are all the address have is_primary set??? and what is your civicrm Version ???

Comment: And do the contacts have the is_deleted set to 0? Just guesswork here...

Comment: SOLVED: this was due to an import bug. During the import some contacts were set as deceased (value 1). The remaining contacts were then set to null by the import tool. But all the elements like Do Not Email if Deceased require a value of 0 for the deceased field. So they wouldn't show on the mailing labels as the system thought they were deceased. 

A simple export of all individuals (contact ID and deceased value), remove those who are deceased and re-import with a value of 0 on the deceased field solved the issue.

Comment: Olly - you can post this as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

This was due to an import bug. During the import some contacts were set as deceased (value 1). The remaining contacts were then set to null by the import tool. But all the elements like Do Not Email if Deceased require a value of 0 for the deceased field. So they wouldn't show on the mailing labels as the system thought they were deceased. A simple export of all individuals (contact ID and deceased value), remove those who are deceased and re-import with a value of 0 on the deceased field solved the issue. –